# Hibernate get list

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Spring with Hibernate in my project. I am getting a list using findAllById in a table which return a list. After that I tried to get another list from the same table with id and otherfield. Now I am getting a list with filtered but not as I expected..

First list contains as follows using class.getById

```
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 6
    id 1 val 2
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 6
    id 1 val 1
```

Now I need to get the following result only using class.getByIdAndVal(1,5)

```
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 5
```

But I am getting the following result

```
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 6
```

What the wrong here, can anyone assist here...

MyClass is as

```
        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> repay = loanService
                .getLoanRepaymentScheduleByLoanId(groupLoan.getLoanId());

        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> rep1 = loanService.getLoanRepaymentScheduleByIdAndMember(loanAc.getId(), 5);
```

I can get the perfect results when I tried with following order

```
        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> rep1 = loanService.getLoanRepaymentScheduleByIdAndMember(loanAc.getId(), 5); 

        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> repay = loanService
                .getLoanRepaymentScheduleByLoanId(groupLoan.getLoanId());
```

But I need the firstone.
My table used here.....

```
    CREATE TABLE entity_loan_repayment_schedule
    (
      loan_id bigint NOT NULL,
      member_amount numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
      member_count integer NOT NULL,
    )
```

Here is my DAO class methods.

```
    public List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> getLoanRepaymentScheduleById(long loanId) {
        Criteria c = commonRepository
                .createCriteria(LoanRepaymentSchedule.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("loanId", Long.valueOf(loanId)));
        c.addOrder(Order.asc("year"));
        c.addOrder(Order.asc("month"));

        return c.list();
    }

    public List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> getLoanRepaymentHistoryByIdAndMember(long loanId, Integer memberCount) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();         
        SQLQuery queryy = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM entity_loan_repayment_schedule WHERE loan_id = :loanId AND member_count= :memberCount");
        queryy.setLong("loanId", loanId);
        queryy.setInteger("memberCount", memberCount);
        queryy.addEntity(LoanRepaymentSchedule.class);      
        return queryy.list();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide details about schema and methods written to get the data.

Comment: why duplicate ids........... they are PK ?

Comment: I'm still not getting what is the exact problem? Can you please try to elaborate more? Also it would be better if you remove unnecessary columns and show data in table.

Comment: @Antoniossss, Yes. loanId is PK in that table.

Comment: @RAS, I am trying to generate a two lists. one is based on id, other one is based on id and member count... I am not getting the exact values in second list.. I updated my question, pls see it, hope it will understandable now

Comment: @Mary.Hansen can't be PK if there are duplicates.

Comment: how do you determine the value for "val" from your second list. I.e. are you sure you're printing the same value that you used in the `select`. Because if you select for `5` and you print it, it should be `5`. Unless you're printing something else (or it has changed meanwhile but let's not assume that).

Comment: @Mary.Hansen I'm not able to see the code calling `getLoanRepaymentHistoryByIdAndMember()` method. Are you sure this method is being executed?

Comment: Sure RAS... Console shows everything that SOP

Comment: @Mary.Hansen Then as geert3 has commented, it's not possible that you're getting wrong data. Or you're doing some really silly mistake.